# Problems With CNTs and Graphene That Must Be Dealt With Before Using Them to Build Tall Buildings Out of THem

Tags: internal-consistency, materials, construction

Buildings of steel and concrete are in big trouble.  The building's steel bones rust when exposed to moisture.  When rusting occurs, the steel expands.  If the steel rusts from inside a concrete shell, the swelling will crack the shell, thus exacerbating the damage.  In fact, it's been brought up again and again on *Life After People* that, if left to their own devices, these buildings wouldn't stand any longer than a century.

There is another problem with the steel-and-concrete mix:  ***weight.***  It is so big an issue, in fact, that they could not be used to build the intended Shimizu Mega-City Pyramid of Tokyo Harbor.  Instead, the plan was to put the construction of the pyramid on hold until the builders could get a hold of lighter, stronger materials.

Currently, there are two such materials in existence--carbon nanotubes and graphene.  These two are subject to much excitement, and there is hope as to their applications.  They could even be used to build megastructures like the Shimizu Pyramid.

But before we should apply carbon nanotubes and graphene into building megabuildings, we first need to compensate whatever physical and chemical problems those two materials pose.  But **what exactly are those problems?**

***(Before anyone brings up scarcity and expensiveness, that's not what I am asking for.)***

Comment: Nitpick: it's steel to expand upon rusting, it's the iron oxide that has a lower density and thus occupy a larger volume.

Comment: Lightning and hot afternoon sun...

Comment: I see no reason to *not* build a skyscraper out of carbon fiber reinforced epoxy. Except that, insurance people and their financial backers being ignorant as they are, that you wont be able to pay the premiums on it. Meaning that nobody will lend you the money to build it. Forget *graphene* and nanotubes. Total bullshit hype. Today off the shelve carbon fibers are all you want.

Comment: @Karl  I said, "no expensiveness".  I'm after the PHYSICAL and CHEMICAL problems, not the ECONOMIC.

Comment: Nobody has ever seen appreciable quantities of graphene and carbon nanotubes. We simply don't know how this materials behave in bulk. We have no idea how to bind them with other materials. There is no idea of how to actually use them as construction materials.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this question is answerable, as asked. Nobody knows any of this yet. This is like asking a Roman engineer what the chemical and physical challenges of using reinforced concrete are. How would he know?

Comment: You might want to try your luck on Physics.SE, there are lots of engineers there that could explain the practical problems better than us.

Comment: @MorrisTheCat  It sounds like you're not even trying.

Answer (score 1):

Graphene and carbon nanotubes are both made out of pure carbon. Which means they burn very well. It might take a decent starting temperature but once they catch fire, you will have a hard time stopping it. Imagine a straw house but much worse.

Comment: I'm not sure that naturally follows. Carbon fiber is used extensively in motorsport but the carbon fiber panels the cars are made of don't burn.

Comment: @MorrisTheCat Well, yes, they do, but not in a way that makes a fire after a crash worse.  The resin softens and deforms and/or chars, and the fibers lose their strength after exposure to the fire and resin breakdown.  Even carbon/carbon degrades in a fire.  Just as a diamond will combust (after breaking down into graphite, as I recall), carbon fiber will combust, just not like gasoline.

Comment: @ZeissIkon right, that's what I meant. I was thinking very much of the poor Mazda Furai. https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/wwfeatures/wm/live/1600_900/images/live/p0/1m/qk/p01mqkhl.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Probably the biggest issue with CNT is that its strength is mainly in tension, along the tubule.  Stress it in a direction that bends the tube, and it will either flex (because the diameter is tiny) or buckle (if the bend is too sharp, like over a knife edge) and break.  This is why resin is used to bond multiple fibers or tubes together -- but the resin can only do so much for compressive stresses.

With graphen, it's an even worse situation -- the material, being effectively two dimensional, hasn't even the level of stiffness of loose CNT.  It has a lot of strength, relative to its mass, in tension in the plane of the sheet, but almost none in compression.

Bottom line, CNT and graphene(s) aren't going to be much better than steel and concrete, or common glass fiber, for compressive loads.

It's worth noting that modern steel/concrete construction is in such widespread use because, as building methods and materials go, it's *light* compared to its strength.  A building as tall as even a modest skyscraper is simply impossible to build (short of having a wider base than its height) with unreinforced stone and brick.  Concrete is very strong in compression, and the steel handles the tension loads.

If there's a building proposal in Japan that can't be built from steel/concrete due to its weight, it's not likely to do better with CNT and graphene.  I'd be a lot more optimistic about aluminum or titanium frame in a foamed or composite form of concrete in order to give similar (or even greater) strength, with less weight, and near-conventional building process.

Comment: So how are we going to work around them?

Comment: @JohnWDailey If I knew that, I wouldn't be fixing power tools on an hourly wage for a living.

Comment: Not to mention that if it's going to be a practical building, rather than just a monument to national ego, there's a limit to how high you can build before the entire building becomes nothing more than a shell for the elevators.

Comment: The Burj (Khalifa?  Dubai?) apparently isnt' at that limit yet.